# Lucene index replication

Tags: indexing, lucene, replication

On a load balanced environment where in i have standalone Java thread(essentially through a spring boot jar for sake of simplicity lets call it Project 1), which reads some metadata and updates lucene indexes at a certain location.

Then There is an actual web application(Project 2) through which I want to query through these indexes(which another Project 1 has created) however the index file, what are the available options:

1. Copy the index file periodically to the lucene of web application which would not be possible as we may have to re kick the application I trust.
2. Maintain both projects as one package in a war and so single instance of lucene is available to both.
3. Any other replication strategy??

Any help on above would be highly appreciated.
Best,
- Vaibhav

Comment: and why can't both apps share a location? Any specific reason?

Comment: Because both of them run in their individual contexts and hence only one of them can access the index file at one point of time, below is essentially the similar problem quoted by someone in quora:https://www.quora.com/How-can-two-applications-share-the-index-built-by-Lucene

Comment: I don't understand the context part , to me its simply an external directory on disk so why can't two applications share it ? Its just the case the directory contains lucene data but a directory being tied to one app is something not making sense to me. Do both applications write or only one writes ?

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on your non functional requirements by your application and any given architectural decision driven by them.

But here some thoughts:

- copy an index like from folderA to folderB sounds like a pretty bad idea. especially if both applications have to run all the time.
- You don't want a direct dependency between these two applications so you have to some kind of build your own lucene component which is serving API functionalities you need.
- I would recommend building a component with a proper API. This component uses lucene as library and in cases like multiple systems or instances like to use this component i would suggest a nice NRT (Near Real Time) implementation of Lucene.